# Magento 2 preview throws error with query string

Tags: magento2, search

I am using elasticsuits and added new optimizer, when tried to preview with query string it is throwing error like
`Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $isUsingAllTokens of Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Spellchecker\Request.`

It is throwing an error related to missing required arguments. After debugging the flow, I manually added one parameter for testing purposes.

Subsequently, it threw an error for the new variable as a missing argument. Errors are also being raised for 'isUsingAllTokens', 'isUsingReference', 'isUsingEdgeNgram', etc.

When I included all the parameters, the application encountered a 500 error without displaying any error message.

Thanks in advance.